# Find the string after a specific substring in mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

I want to retrieve the last part of a large string in mysql after occurence of a particular substring. Please advice about how to do that.

For e.g. the main string contains 
"New Delhi is capitalof India".
"Berlin is capitalof Germany".

I need to retrieve only India and Germany. I want know how to retrieve the data occuring after the specific substring like 'capitalof'.

I need to do this in mysql.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
select
substring_index(title,'capitalof',-1)
from table1
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49f7/1)